# TensorFlow endorsed vgg-19 model/feature extractor

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, autodiff, vgg-net

My task requires me to extract features from the pool5 layer of vgg-19 net. Previously I was doing it using Caffe and then working on the extracted features using Tensorflow for further training. But now, I want to add a deconv layer on top and fine-tune the entire net for end-to-end training. Now my gradients are obtained using tensroflow while I had obtained the features from vgg-19 using caffe ,so I guess it will be difficult to backpropagate these gradients to caffe. So that is the reason I am looking for a vgg-19 model in tensorflow that can he used for extracting features from any layer. I found some projects online but they are not officially endorsed by Tensorflow.

Comment: Keras has a VGG-19 module in keras.applications.

Comment: Thanks Matias but I was looking for something in tensorflow because I have already coded my couple of layers and a compliated objective function in tensorflow and it will take more time to port all that code back to keras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `tensorflow` you can use the `TF-Slim library` and use the `pretrained models` which are available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim). You can check their useful [slim walk through notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb) on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks vijay for your answer! So just a followup question. Are you aware of its performance as compared to caffe?

Comment: Last time i checked(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.07249.pdf) tf performance is not as good as caffe, but i am not sure about the recent versions.

Comment: @vijaym unfortunately, the links you have provided is not active any more